# postgresql auth against samba active directory

Tags: samba, authentication, postgresql, active-directory

I've recently set up a new Samba4 Active Directory to handle centralized authentication for my small office network. On this server is also a postgresql-9.5 instance, and I'm trying to have it authenticate against the AD. Recognizing the difference between *authentication* (this is what I need) and *authorization* (I believe this is handled entirely within postgresql once the user has been authenticated), I'm running into problems.

The AD is rather vanilla at the moment, closely following [this howto](https://jimshaver.net/2016/05/30/setting-up-an-active-directory-domain-controller-using-samba-4-on-ubuntu-16-04/). I've set up some users and the basic kerberos authentication appears to be working (done with `kinit myusername@SAMDOM.MYDOMAIN.TLD`, verified with `klist`). Similarly, `smbclient //myhost.samdom.mydomain.tld/netlogon -U 'myusername'` works.

The localhost is resolving to the samba AD and DNS forwarding is going upstream correctly. These work:

```
$ host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.samdom.mydomain.tld
$ host -t SRV _kerberos._udp.samdom.mydomain.tld
$ host -t A myhost.samdom.mydomain.tld
```

BTW: ubuntu-16.04 server, postgresql-9.5, samba-4.3.9

## Question:

What am I missing in the configuration of samba and/or postgres to enable authentication against the AD?

## DB Setup

Basic connectivity with postgresql appears to be good: it's listening on the appropriate interfaces (all for now), the `postgres` user can access things locally without a problem. I set up a simple database, output from `\list`:

```
   Name    |   Owner    | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
-----------+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 pgtest2   | myusername | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

with users listed (per [this query](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1121195544.8208.242.camel@state.g2switchworks.com)):

```
 User name  | User ID |    Attributes
------------+---------+-------------------
 myusername |   16384 | create database
 postgres   |      10 | superuser, create+
            |         | database
```

## Failing Auth

However, when I try on the console:

```
$ psql -h myhost.samdom.mydomain.tld -U myusername@SAMDOM.MYDOMAIN.TLD -d pgtest2
psql: GSSAPI continuation error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
GSSAPI continuation error: No Kerberos credentials available
```

From `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log`:

```
myusername@SAMDOM.MYDOMAIN.TLD@pgtest2 LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
myusername@SAMDOM.MYDOMAIN.TLD@pgtest2 FATAL:  GSSAPI authentication failed for user "myusername@SAMDOM.MYDOMAIN.TLD"
myusername@SAMDOM.MYDOMAIN.TLD@pgtest2 DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 92: "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 gss krb_realm=SAMDOM.MYDOMAIN.TLD include_realm=1 map=krb"
```

## Config Files

The config file (portions) that I think are appropriate and necessary:

- `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf`:

  ```
  local   all             postgres                                peer
  local   all             all                                     peer
  host all all 0.0.0.0/0 gss krb_realm=SAMDOM.MYDOMAIN.TLD include_realm=1 map=krb
  host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
  host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
  ```
- `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgres.conf`:

  ```
  krb_server_keyfile = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/postgres.keytab'
  ```

  (The keytab was generated with: `samba-tool domain exportkeytab postgres.keytab  -U postgres/myhost.samdom.mydomain.tld@SAMDOM.MYDOMAIN.TLD`, is mode 400, and owned by `postgres:postgres`.)
- `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

  ```
  # Global parameters
  [global]
          workgroup = SAMDOM
          realm = SAMDOM.MYDOMAIN.TLD
          netbios name = MYHOST
          interfaces = lo eno1
          bind interfaces only = Yes
          server role = active directory domain controller
          dns forwarder = 11.22.33.254
          idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes
          tls enabled =  yes
          tls keyfile = tls/key.pem
          tls certfile = tls/cert.pem
          tls cafile = tls/ca.pem
  [netlogon]
          path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/samdom.mydomain.tld/scripts
          read only = No
  [sysvol]
          path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
          read only = No
  ```

Comment: Comments are welcome on how to improve the question, what more to include, or other methods to facilitate discourse. (I wish I could provide more bounty from my SO account ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I faced the task of authentication of postgress users against samba4 AD domain controller and I found the solution [in this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20171124121238/https://www.openscg.com/2017/07/setting-up-ldap-with-active-directory-in-postgresql/).
As you can see, the pg_hba.conf entry in your case would be:

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 ldap ldapserver=localhost ldapprefix="" ldapsuffix="@SAMDOM.MYDOMAIN.TLD"
```

or if you prefer authenticate users in the form DOMAIN\username:

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 ldap ldapserver=localhost ldapprefix="SANDOM\" ldapsuffix=""
```

The rol must be created in the database in addition to AD because authorization mechanism, as you noted above, is done inside postgres.
Then restart postgresql and try connection.

The downside is that you'll get the error "*Strong(er) authentication required*" in postgres log, so you must disable the Strong ldap authorization in samba conf file, adding this at global setcion:

```
ldap server require strong auth = No
```

Comment: Thanks Isidoro, I'll look into this a bit more. I'm not thrilled about decreasing "strong auth" in samba, so I need to read into the implications of that.

Comment: BTW: stale link, since OpenSCG was purchased by Amazon and that page is now not right. Unless/until it is properly re-published, the web archive has it available from [2017 Nov 24](https://web.archive.org/web/20171124121238/https://www.openscg.com/2017/07/setting-up-ldap-with-active-directory-in-postgresql/).

Comment: Thank you r2evans. I've updated the link to web.archive.

Comment: I should have accepted this a long time ago. I'm still not happy with the answer, but that's because of several of the nuances with Samba4 and ancillary authentication of other libraries/apps. I apologize for waiting so long to give you the credit, Isidoro.